# How to save a for-loop as a Gif file in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, animation, plot, gif

I would like to create a Gif with XY data adding a new point each time in my plot. I would like to see an accumulative sequence of my data in a Gif. In the first frame the plot should be show a point, in the second two points, and in the last frame all points.

For that, I was trying to save as a Gif a for-loop, but I have two problems that I can't resolve. First, the Gif only save the last frame or image with all points. Second, when I use `par(new=TRUE)` the Gift is saved, but only one point in each frame.
I was trying to set a transparent background colour in the plot, but it was not possible.

Here is an example:

```
x  <- 1:10
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(10)
graphics.off()     

library(animation)
ani.options(convert = 'C:/PROGRA~1/ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16/magick.exe') # update the folder name to your software version.
saveGIF({

  for (i in 1:10) {
    plot(x[i], y[i], pch=1, type="b", col="red", xlim = c(1,10), ylim = c(-1, 2))
    Sys.sleep(0.5) 
    par(new=TRUE)
  }
}, movie.name = "test.gif", ani.width = 1000, ani.height = 500, nmax = 50, interval =0.5)
```

Any way to resolve this problem would be welcome.

Comment: `plot(x[seq_len(i)], y[seq_len(i)], ...`?

Comment: @Roland nice but the gif show me only the last frame